# What does "A version conflict was detected when attempting to index this document." mean in Azure Search?

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

My indexer is failing with the message

> A version conflict was detected when attempting to index this
>   document. Please try again.

What is this referring to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error indicates that multiple documents with the same document key are being indexed at the same time. This can happen in several situations:

1. You have multiple indexers writing to the same index. One way of mitigating this situation is to stagger different indexers' schedule to avoid them overlapping as much as possible.
2. Your datasource actually has multiple items that map to the same document key.
3. You're using some other code in addition to indexer to push data into your index. Occasional conflicts between documents with the same key may be unavoidable, but if you're running your indexer on a schedule, indexing will still make forward progress.

HTH!

Comment: Thanks! I found some duplicate rows in our data.

Answer (score 0):

This issue happens when your INDEX VALUES are not unique. Make sure that Key Attribute is Unique in your Index Definition.